# PHP MySQL Grouping Issue

Tags: php, mysql

If I have a table with the following data in MySQL:

```
Company           CompanyEntity        OrderNumber      Delivery Date
Deeway HS              20779             4608580         2020-11-11
Deeway Pearl HS        20780             4608580         2020-11-11
Deeway Stony HS        1273              4608558         2020-11-11
Zaper LTD              9995              4630230         2020-11-11
Zaper CP LTD           4295              4607371         2020-11-11
Wilder                 4224              6630210         2020-11-11
Wilder                 4224              7601371         2020-11-11
```

I need it to look like this:

```
Company                                        CompanyEntity        OrderNumber      Delivery Date
Deeway HS,Deeway Pearl HS,Deeway Stony HS     20779,20780,1273     4608580,4608558    2020-11-11
Zaper LTD,Zaper CP LTD                           9995,4295         4630230,4607371    2020-11-11
Wilder                                             4224            6630210,7601371    2020-11-11
```

I've tried:

```
SELECT
nextgenorder_companyname,
nextgenorder_company_entity,
nextgenorder_ordernumber,
nextgenorder_deliverydate
    FROM nextgenorders2
WHERE nextgenorder_deliverydate='2020-11-11'
GROUP BY nextgenorder_companyname,nextgenorder_company_entity
ORDER BY nextgenorder_companyname
```

Which does not give me the results I want. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/220066/2/0)

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `GROUP_CONCAT` to aggregate your values, and based on your sample data you want to group by the first word in the name, so you can use [`SUBSTRING_INDEX`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) to extract that. To deal with possible `/` in the name as a separator instead of space, you can `REPLACE` them:

```
SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT nextgenorder_companyname) AS Company,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT nextgenorder_company_entity) AS CompanyEntity,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT nextgenorder_ordernumber) AS OrderNumber,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT nextgenorder_deliverydate) AS `Delivery Date`
FROM nextgenorders2
WHERE nextgenorder_deliverydate='2020-11-11'
GROUP BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(REPLACE(nextgenorder_companyname, '/', ' '), ' ',1)
ORDER BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(REPLACE(nextgenorder_companyname, '/', ' '), ' ',1)
```

Output:

```
Company                                     CompanyEntity       OrderNumber         Delivery Date
Deeway HS,Deeway Pearl HS,Deeway Stony HS   20779,20780,1273    4608580,4608558     2020-11-11
Wilder                                      4224                6630210,7601371     2020-11-11
Zaper/LTD,Zaper CP LTD                      9995,4295           4630230,4607371     2020-11-11
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/32c4ed/1)

Comment: On a cell phone, can't beat you +1.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you! Last question, I can use the same query to update and/or insert as well, correct?

Comment: @KyoceraAlerts If any inputs like here **date value** comes from a user, then you must take care of the value. Otherwise it may causes sql injection. In that case, I would suggest you use mysqli or PDO.

Comment: `ORDER BY nextgenorder_companyname` should fail with `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` mode.

Comment: Some of the company names have slashes(/) in the name. For example Zaper/LTD. I tried mysqli_set_charset($mysqli,"utf8"); but it didn't work. How do you handle special characters with GROUP CONCAT?

Comment: I ended up putting a trigger on the table to replace / with a space. Thanks again

Comment: @PaulSpiegel thanks for pointing that out, I've corrected the query.

Comment: @KyoceraAlerts you can deal with the `/` in the query, please see my edit and the updated demo.